# Remove a drawing using Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a drawing on a sheet that I use to indicate its a draft copy. When appropriate, this drawing needs to be removed.

Is it possible to remove a drawing using Google Sheets API?

i.e. the equivalent of this in google apps script, but using Sheets API:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheets()[0].getDrawings()[0].remove();
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK Google Sheets API does not provide a direct method for manipulating drawings or shapes within a spreadsheet. The Google Sheets API primarily focuses on reading and writing cell-based data. Have a look at Google Apps Script service if you want to programmatically manipulate drawings or shapes in a Google Sheets document.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the code I've used as an example is google apps script. Ideally, I would like to achieve this in Sheets API, but perhaps it isn't possible

Comment: About `Remove a drawing using Google Sheets API`, in your situation, do you want to achieve this from outside of Google? If my understanding is correct, I think that the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script can be a workaround for achieving this. But, I cannot know your actual situation from your question. If my guess was not correct, I apologize.